# Generate BigQuery code from dplyr code *without* actually executing BigQuery?

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery, dbplyr, bigrquery

We can see [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery) some simple instructions on how to use tidyverse principles to wrangle data using bigquery using the R packages bigrquery and dbplyr.

This works by taking regular `dplyr` code and when the user calls `%>% collect()`, it translates the dplyr code into BigQuery's flavor of SQL, then executes the BigQuery code in BigQuery

I would like to know if I could use these packages to simply generate the raw BigQuery code, but not execute it?

What I am ultimately after is a way to generate BigQuery code from dplyr *without* actually using BigQuery (e.g. if working offline, for example)

#### What I know so far

I know it's possible to write dplyr code, call `%>% collect()` and view the BigQuery code that was generated/run in the GCP console in the browser. I would like the same code returned as a string in RStudio (and without it ever being executed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `collect()`, just type `%>% show_query()` at the end of your `dplyr`-code.

Comment: That sounds great. Do you know if this can work offline? I think perhaps not because it requires some pointer to a BigQuery table?

Comment: I tried it on `iris` and get `no applicable method for 'show_query' applied to an object of class "data.frame"`, which is understandable

Comment: no it hast to be a database connection which you apply your (db)dplyr code upon